# Install driver not showing WiFi network anymore

Tags: 18.04, wireless, 20.04, iwlwifi

Every now and then I do a clean install of Ubuntu, and every time I am able to select WiFi networks during installation. For some reasons now it only shows "Intel corporation".

The only thing I can think that might have caused the problem are:

1. A failed attempt to install Ubuntu 20.04 (likely because of a firmware issue). Now trying to revert to Ubuntu 18.04
2. Resetting my BIOS settings (Taichi X299 motherboard)

These are the wireless [card specs](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=pci:8086-24fb-8086-2110).

Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Your wireless card is not supported by the kernel that ships with 18.04. You'll need at least 5.5, which means the latest 20.04 LTS (if the .iso was made after Feb. 9, 2021) or 20.10.

Comment: @Matigo that's not true. It was working fine with 18.04 , something happened and it doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was the "WAN Radio" settings that was reset to "Auto" when it seems it should be "Enabled"

(UEFI => Advanced => Chipset Configuration => WAN Radio)

You might also have to make sure the "BIOS" button on the WiFi card, is turned on (outside your computer case, at the back, no need to open it).